# concurrent login to linux machine using perl

Tags: perl, telnet, expect

As part of concurrent testing, i have to login to a linux server using telnet concurrently. I need a maximum of 50 logins to the servers. I am able to write a simple script using perl expect but the session ends once it goes to the next item in the loop. Can someone help out on how to do this? ALso the below implementation does the connection serially and not concurrently.

```
for(my $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

  my $exp = Expect->spawn("telnet abc") or die "Cannot spawn telnet: $!\n";

  $exp->expect($timeout, "Login:");
  $exp->send("$username\n");

  $exp->expect($timeout, "Password:");
  $exp->send("$password\n");
}
```

Comment: Call `sleep 999;` so the script doesn't end?

Comment: I can sleep for it to remain for ever. If i have to login concurrently i dont know how to do. I have updated my question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do all the work in Perl:

```
my %users = (
    'name1' => 'pw1',
    'name2' => 'pw2',
    # ...
    'name50' => 'pw50',
);
my @sessions;

while (my ($user, $pass) = each %users) {
    my $exp = Expect->spawn("telnet abc")
        or die "Cannot spawn telnet: $!\n";
    $exp->expect($timeout, "Login:");
    $exp->send("$user\n");
    $exp->expect($timeout, "Password:");
    $exp->send("$pass\n");
    push @sessions, $exp;
}

# now that you're all logged in, logout
for my $exp (@sessions) {
    $exp->send("exit\n");
    $exp->expect('eof');   # I'm not sure this is correct
}
```